# iOS app doesn't go into suspension

Tags: ios

I've created a new project and added an infinite loop to `applicationDidEnterBackground`.

```
    while ( true)
{
    NSLog(@"Running");
}
```

The loop keps running for minutes, never ends, while according to the apple docs and my experience it should be suspended after ~5 seconds.

Why doesn't it ?

Comment: Are you sure it continues running for minutes and you're not confusing stdout flush time with actual run time?

Comment: Does it run that long _only while attached to the debugger_ or does it also run that long when you run the app on the phone _without_ the debugger? Running inside the debugger is treated differently by the OS.

Comment: @DarkDust I think that it may be the case, but why doesn't apple describe it anywhere.

Ian MacDonald: I don't think I am. I've set my NSLOG to launch every 1000000 loop iterations or so and it still runs infinitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS treats apps running in the debugger differently and doesn't apply the 5-second rule here. This rule is also not applied to `applicationWillTerminate:` when attached to the debugger (doesn't matter much any more).

The reason is simple: you wouldn't be able to debug those methods if your app would get killed after 5 seconds. You wouldn't have time to do any meaningful analysis.

I'm not aware of any document describing this, though.

Comment: What's interesting though, that when I use `AFNetworking` I don't get success/failure callbacks  (as if the app suspended) while I start them in `didEnterBackground` unless I use a background task (while debugging too).